# Setting Docker ENV using python -c "command"

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

The python modules that I downloaded are inside the user's home directory. I need to set the python path to the user's bin profile. I tried two approaches as shown below in my dockerfile but to no avail. When I check the environment variable in the running container for the first case the PY_USER BIN is `$(python -c 'import site; print(site.USER_BASE + "/bin")')` and for the second case the PY_USER_BIN is blank. However, when I manually try to export the PY_USER_BIN variable, it works.

`ENV PY_USER_BIN $(python -c 'import site; print(site.USER_BASE + "/bin")')`

`ENV PATH $PY_USER_BIN:$PATH`

and

`RUN export PY_USER_BIN=$(python -c 'import site; print(site.USER_BASE + "/bin")')`

`ENV PATH $PY_USER_BIN:$PATH`

Comment: afaik you cannot use shell command substitution in an ENV statement. as for the second case, I had similar issues. we solved it by writing a custom launcher/entrypoint script that sets the required env variables and then executes the actual command....

Comment: ...as a side note, I guess the reason your second attempt fails is because RUN actually executes your command in a subshell (see shell form: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) ...so you really are executing ```/bin/sh -c export PY_USER_BIN=...```, hence the environment variable is set in the subshell's context and is lost once docker processes the following ENV statement...

Comment: Docker doesn't usually have concepts of "user" or "home directory"; since a Docker image filesystem is completely isolated from everything else, normal practice is to just `pip install` dependencies into the "system" Python (isolated from the host Python and other containers' Python).  Can you do this, and skip setting these environment variables altogether?

Answer (score 0):

To me you mix different context of execution.

The `ENV` command that you use is a Dockerfile command, it is for env variable in the context of docker that would be forwarded to the container.

The `RUN` command execute a command inside the container, here, `export`. Whatever is done inside the container stay inside the container and docker will not have access to it.

For me there no point to give as docker ENV variable where python is on the host has they don't share the same file system. If you need to do it on the container context, then run these command inside the container context with standard shell commands.

Try that first by connecting to your container and running a shell inside it, once the commands works, put them in your Dockerfile. That's as simple as that. To do that run it like:

```
docker run -ti [your container name/tag] [your shell]
```

if you use sh as shell:

```
docker run -ti [your container name/tag] sh
```

Then try your commands.

To me it seems the commands you want would look like that:

```
RUN export PY_USER_BIN=$(python -c 'import site; print(site.USER_BASE + "/bin")')
RUN export PATH=$PY_USER_BIN:$PATH
```

Anyway the point of a container is to have a fixed file system, fixed user names and all. So the USER_BIN shall be always in the same path inside the container in 99% case you could has well hardcode it.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas! I know that it does work manually when I run the command directly in the container, however I was curious to know if there was a way to do this through the Dockerfile.